# how to install numpy package in Databricks cluster

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, databricks

I am using `umap` and `hdbscan` packages for clustering.

while using the `umap` package, it needs `numpy 1.20` and less version. in my databricks cluster numpy version is `1.21.0.`

I tried all the options like uninstalling using `sudo, pip, pip3` the latest version and installing using `pip, pip3, --upgrade numpy==1.19.2`

Still it shows numpy version 1.21.0.

kindly suggest me any other options to get solve this package version related issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are potentially using the wrong `pip`, this happens a lot when in a system with more than one Python version. I would recommend you to use pip as a module from the Python you use, for instance:

```
python -m pip install numpy==1.21.0
```

Or consider using `which` to make sure you are using `pip` for the correct `python` binary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `%pip install numpy==<version>` command instead - it will take care for installing library to all nodes, and restarting Python interpreter (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html)).  But take into account that this may break other libraries that depend on specific version of numpy.

But it's really interesting that you have 1.21.0 - if you check [release notes for Databricks Runtimes](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/releases.html) you can see that all latest versions have 1.19.2.